# How to create Dataflow job without External ip to dataflow worker?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am running dataflow job using python code.

I want my dataflow workers to have only private ips to it, external ips should not be assigned.

The reason for this is, i am accessing mongodb atlas from dataflow and its only accessible from private ips (because vpc peering is done).

I tried many command line options while launching job:

```
--disable-public-ips , --no_use_public_ips , --usePublicIps=false
```

but no success. How can i achieve that?

Comment: --no_use_public_ips is the right option.  How are you passing it, and what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Are you also specifying the network or the subnetwork?

Comment: What is your full command when you run your job?

Comment: "python3 mongo.py --no_use_public_ips --requirements_file requirements.txt"                                
is the full command i am using.

When dataflow workers are created, i am expending it to have only private ip. however, it has both the private and public ips.

I have tried --network, subnetwork, --disable-public-ips , --no_use_public_ips , --usePublicIps=false  parameters in this command. but no success.

Comment: @PeterKim, yes i have specified network and subnetwork in python code. also tried passing it from command line while running python code.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue !!

The problem was, i had specified network, subnetwork parameters inside my code.

As per dataflow document one of those two values should be specified. So i commented network value and issue solved